# Cannot import javax.servlet after adding dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I cannot import javax.servlet even though I have already added the package in my gradle dependencies.

Here's my gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', 
    ...
    ...
}
```

I've also tried:

```
dependencies {
    compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0.1" 
}
```

But when I import it using:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

I get the error: Cannot resolve symbol "HttpServletResponse".

Comment: `javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0.1` is missing a `javax.`. It should be `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1`

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1' 
    ...
    ...
}
```

as i think the `comma` at the end is causing issues because you dont need commas to separate dependencies so remove it also i suggest you specifying `version`